# The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Hello Every One The Following Error Comes To Me Suddenly When I Changed Simple And Few Thing On My Stored Procedure Code And It Was Working Great And If I Cleared The Updated Code It Works Fine Again So I Do Not Know What Is The Reason 
And Here Is The Error "**The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction**"

Thanks In Advance

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]
    @English Bit = 0 , 
    @ID BigInt  =  NULL Output  , 
    @Company_ID SmallInt  =  NULL , 
    @Cust_ID NVarChar (20) =  NULL , 
    @Cust_Cat NVarChar (10) =  NULL , 
    @Debit_Limit Decimal (18,3) =  NULL , 
    @From_Date NVarChar (19) =  NULL , 
    @To_Date NVarChar (19) =  NULL , 
    @User_ID NVarChar(50) = NULL 
As
BEGIN
  Create Table #Errors (ErrorNumber int Not Null, ErrorValue nvarchar(300) Collate Arabic_CI_AS Null);
  Begin Tran trn_INV_CustDebLim_setupInsert;
  Begin Try
    Insert Into INV_Cust_Debit_Limit_setup
    (  Company_ID ,  Cust_ID ,  Cust_Cat ,  Debit_Limit ,  From_Date ,  To_Date  ) 
    Values
    ( @Company_ID , @Cust_ID , @Cust_Cat , @Debit_Limit , @From_Date , @To_Date  ) 
    set @ID = @@IDENTITY
    -- From Here Is New Part --
    declare @str nvarchar(50)
    IF(@Cust_ID IS NOT NULL)
        set @str = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ' + @Cust_ID 
    IF(@Cust_Cat IS NOT NULL)
        set @str += 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ' + @Cust_Cat
    set @str += ' xxxxx' +@Debit_Limit + '  xxxx xx' +@From_Date
    IF(@English = 1)
        BEGIN
            IF(@Cust_ID IS NOT NULL)
                set @str = 'Credit Limit Added On Customer ' + @Cust_ID
            IF(@Cust_Cat IS NOT NULL)
                set @str += 'Credit Limit Added On Customer Category ' + @Cust_Cat
            set @str = ' With Value ' +@Debit_Limit + ' From Date ' +@From_Date
        END
    exec usp_GLApplicationAudit @Company_ID , NULL , 10 , @User_ID , @str ,@ID ,10, NULL , NULL ,NULL ,NULL,NULL,'SAl'
    -- To Here Is New Part --
  End Try
  Begin Catch
      Insert #Errors Values(1002,ERROR_MESSAGE());      
      Goto Finished;
  End Catch
-- Return Error Records
Finished:
    -- retrieve Errors and commit/Rollbak Trans.
    If (Select count(E.ErrorNumber)
            From #Errors E Left Join GVT_Errors G
                On E.ErrorNumber = G.Err_Number
            Where G.Err_Type=0 ) > 0
        Begin
            -- The Following are Errors
            Select E.ErrorNumber As [Err_No], G.MessageA + ': ' + E.ErrorValue As [Err_Desc], Err_Source, dbo.fn_GetItemDescription('Err_Type',Cast(Err_Type As nvarchar), null, null, null, null, 0) As Err_Type_Desc, Err_Type, SeverityLevel As [Severity], CategoryID
              From #Errors E Left Join GVT_Errors G 
                On E.ErrorNumber = G.Err_Number;
            Rollback Tran trn_INV_CustDebLim_setupInsert;
        End
    Else
        Begin
            -- The Following Not Errors They are Warnings or Information
            Select E.ErrorNumber As [Err_No], G.MessageA + ': ' + E.ErrorValue As [Err_Desc], Err_Source, dbo.fn_GetItemDescription('Err_Type',Cast(Err_Type As nvarchar), null, null, null, null, 0) As Err_Type_Desc, Err_Type, SeverityLevel As [Severity], CategoryID
              From #Errors E Left Join GVT_Errors G 
                On E.ErrorNumber = G.Err_Number;
            Commit Tran trn_INV_CustDebLim_setupInsert;
        End
    DROP Table #Errors;

END
```

Answer (score 3):

In the CATCH code you **must** check the state of [`XACT_STATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189797.aspx) and act accordingly. For a procedure template that handles transactions and try/catch blocks correctly see [Exception Handling and Nested Transactions](http://rusanu.com/2009/06/11/exception-handling-and-nested-transactions/):

```
create procedure [usp_my_procedure_name]
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @trancount int;
    set @trancount = @@trancount;
    begin try
        if @trancount = 0
            begin transaction
        else
            save transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        -- Do the actual work here

lbexit:
        if @trancount = 0   
            commit;
    end try
    begin catch
        declare @error int, @message varchar(4000), @xstate int;
        select @error = ERROR_NUMBER(), @message = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @xstate = XACT_STATE();
        if @xstate = -1
            rollback;
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount = 0
            rollback
        if @xstate = 1 and @trancount > 0
            rollback transaction usp_my_procedure_name;

        raiserror ('usp_my_procedure_name: %d: %s', 16, 1, @error, @message) ;
    end catch   
end
```